# Scroll up a ScrollView slowly

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

The question is "How do i scroll up a ScrollView to top very smoothly and slowly".

In my special case i need to scroll to top in about 1-2 seconds.
Ive tried interpolating manually using a Handler (calling scrollTo(0, y)) but that didnt work at all.

I've seen this effect on some bookreader-apps yet, so there must be a way, im sure :D.
(Text is very slowly scrolling up to go on reading without touching the screen, doing input).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 2 seconds move the scroll view to the possition of 2000

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 20) {          

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {     
   scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (2000 - millisUntilFinished)); // from zero to 2000    
 }          

 public void onFinish() {  
 }      

}.start();
```

Comment: Hey, I didnt know about the CountDownTimer, thus that alone earns a "thanks" :). Finally, it was solved with a CountDownTimer but with modified code. Scrolling is done by scrollBy instead of scrollTo to can specify easyily a "scrollSpeed". Additionally i've added a functionallity to just scroll up to the top and then we're finish. (Not starting anywhere else like at the bottom etc and scroll still up if we are already on the top).

Comment: Yes that is a good way to use scrollBy, easier to adjust the movement. Perhaps you should post your solution as pople often ask this question ;)

Comment: hi lumis i am facing the same problem.. could you please look at my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724249/how-to-move-scrollview-slowly-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-android) please..thanks

Comment: @Michael i am facing the same problem.. could you please look at my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724249/how-to-move-scrollview-slowly-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-android) please..thanks

Comment: how to scroll from particular view to bottom of view

Answer (score 31):

I did it using object animator (Available in API >= 3) and it looks very good:

Define an ObjectAnimator:
`final ObjectAnimator animScrollToTop = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "scrollY", 0);`

(`this` refers to the class extending Android's `ScrollView`)

you can set its duration as you wish:

`animScrollToTop.setDuration(2000);` (2 seconds)

P.s. Don't forget to start the animation.

Comment: 0 is the parameter to where you want to scroll to

Comment: @Arlind Sorry if it is late a bit 
you can place the width or height of the component that you want to scroll instead of ZERO

Answer (score 13):

Try the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    ValueAnimator realSmoothScrollAnimation = 
        ValueAnimator.ofInt(parentScrollView.getScrollY(), targetScrollY);
    realSmoothScrollAnimation.setDuration(500);
    realSmoothScrollAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            int scrollTo = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            parentScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollTo);
        }
    });

    realSmoothScrollAnimation.start();
}
else
{
    parentScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, targetScrollY);
}
```

Comment: it is smooth, having different problems with what I am currently trying to do, but this definitely achieves smooth scrolling

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `smoothScrollTo(int x, int y)`?
You can't set the speed parameter but maybe this function will be ok for you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Timer and TimerTask class. You could do something like

```
scrollTimer = new Timer();
scrollerSchedule = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        runOnUiThread(SCROLL TO CODE GOES HERE);
    }
};
scrollTimer.schedule(scrollerSchedule, 30, 30);
```