# Scrolling Image on Android

Tags: android, image, animation, drawable

I want to make an animated background on a splash screen.  How can I scroll an image across the screen.

I am currently using an animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="10000"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:fromXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

The problem is the image size is currently set to fill the parent, so as it scrolls I can see the borders of the image.  Is it possible to have an image with a size larger than the parent size. This way I can still let it scroll,without ever seeing the borders.

Comment: Not anything feasible.  One suggestion is to put the image on scroll view and programmatically scrolling it.

Comment: thanks but still confussed...put image in scrollview background or imageview?

Comment: if you have worked on it could you please post the code?

Comment: Try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202193/scroll-up-a-scrollview-slowly