# Android Studio How to set ScrollView to Scroll "SLOWLY" downward

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I already have the code for scrolling the scrollview all the way down onCreate. But my problem is the code I used to achieve this makes autoscrolling to fast. I need to slowly scroll the scrollview down. I need to do this because I have a narator that is reading the content of my work. Therefor I want to automatically scroll the content downward while the narator is reading it. To achieve this I use the following code:

```
final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
    sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    },100L);
```

and also here is all of my code

```
package org.intercode.lifeatceu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class pm extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout ll;
MediaPlayer mpPM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pm);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    mpPM = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.pm);
    mpPM.start();

    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
    sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    },100L);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainmenu,menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.menu_home:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, mainmenu.class));
            mpPM.stop();

            break;
        case R.id.menu_browse:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, browse.class));
            mpPM.stop();

            break;
        case R.id.menu_quiz:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Chooselevel.class));
            mpPM.stop();

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    mpPM.stop();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), browse.class));

}
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    mpPM.stop();
}

}
```

My question here is, how can I change the speed of the scrolling?

Comment: You might find some hints in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202193/scroll-up-a-scrollview-slowly

Comment: Use `smoothScrollBy(dx, dy)` instead of `fullScroll()`. You will have to find the total height of the `TextView` containing the text you wish to scroll, and then repeatedly call `smoothScrollBy(dx, dy)` until you reach the end. The speed can then be controlled by increasing/decrasing the `dx` value or by increasing the timer between each call to `smoothScrollBy(dx, dy)`.

Comment: you mean i just have to replace it by smoothscrollby dx,dy???? or i need to make a timer?

Comment: I think you will have to do both, replace and make a timer. Then you can adjust the speed by adjusting the dx-value or the timer.

Comment: ok i already have the answer...final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000000, 50)
        {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                sv.scrollBy(0,1);
            }
            public void onFinish() {

            }

Comment: but my problem now is how to stop the timer when the user scroll up or what ever

Comment: do you have idea in if statement which i can check if the sv is scrolled up then if it is scrolled up my timer will stop