# Android .. Auto scroll TextView with bar

Tags: android, scroll, textview, auto

I am trying to make a bar that control the scrolling speed of the text inside TextView

Like this one ...

[ReadApp Auto Scroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPLW0oZmewQ)

I tried some ways but what i only get immediately scroll to bottom

Comment: You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340839/android-studio-how-to-set-scrollview-to-scroll-slowly-downward) and its comments